# Models Defined As Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First with an existing database. For some reason, it created what appear to be my models as controllers (in the controllers directory and part of the controllers namespace). Is there a reason it did this? Are these actually controllers? New to MVC framework...

See the image below. The ASP.NET identity tables were created as controllers, when they should be models.

[image]

Comment: Unless those classes inherit from `Controller`, or implement `IController`, no. Did you actually open one of those files?

Comment: That makes sense. I did look in the folders and was put off by it naming it in the namespace `MyApp.Controllers` but it doesn't actually inherit `Controller`. I wonder why it placed them there? I can probably safely move them.

Comment: Not sure. I never seen it do that. Which project template are you using? And yes, you can safely move them, though I would check the namespacing. The template may have just put them there because those models have no real use outside of initializing authentication/authorization, which seems like tasks isolated to the Account controller, especially with the OWIN templates.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj200620.aspx I'm changing the namespace to `MyApp.Models` and moving them to the Models directory. I'm hoping this isn't indicative of a larger problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the classes don't inherit from `Controll` or implement `IController`, they're not actually controllers. I moved them to the Models directory and into the `Models` namespace.